# What is the problem with my Python authentication script?

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping, login-script

I'm trying to login to a specific site in Python, but without success. Any helpers?

```
import requests
url = 'https://us0.forgeofempires.com/page/'
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0'
session = requests.Session()
session.headers['User-Agent'] = user_agent
_xsrf = session.cookies.get('_xsrf', domain='.forgeofempires.com')
login = session.post(url, {
    'login[userid]':'user',
    'login[password]':'pass',
    '_xsrf':_xsrf
})
print(login)
f = open('results.html', 'w', encoding = 'utf-8')
f.write(login.text)
f.close()
```

Comment: What was unsuccessful about your attempt?

Comment: *You* tell *us* what the problem you are experiencing is and  *maybe* we can figure out why. But you have provided no error messages, no stack traces, no exceptions, nothing. And we can't run your code since we don't have the user id and password.

Comment: Given valid credentials, your code will work

Comment: I would think you cannot retrieve cookies before you visit a page with `session.get` or `session.post`. So do a `get` of the login page first before your `post` and there should be no need to explicitly set `_xsrf` as a `post` parameter if is sufficient for it to be resent up as a cookie.

Comment: Sorry. Here is the result.  I get Response 200 message but when I open my results.html it still shows me a login page without being logged in... Also, when analysing network traffic when logging in manually, I don't see POST request at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

The following code finally works. I had to figure out by trial and error the fewest headers that needed to be set to get this to work. And, of course, as I previously stated, it is necessary to first visit the URL https://us.forgeofempires.com/glps/iframe-login to have the necessary cookies downloaded before you can proceed with sending the login POST (it is also necessary to extract from the cookies the 'XRRF-TOKEN' value and use this to set the 'x-xsrf-token' header value). And in my earlier attempt I was erroneously sending up the form encoded as JSON.

Note that the output is in JSON format; it is not HTML. Your output file should probably have the file extension of `.json`.

```py
import requests

initial_url = 'https://us.forgeofempires.com/glps/iframe-login'
login_url = 'https://us.forgeofempires.com/glps/login_check'

session = requests.Session()
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0'
session.headers['User-Agent'] = user_agent
r = session.get(initial_url)

xsrf_token = session.cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN', domain='us.forgeofempires.com')

session.headers['x-xsrf-token'] = xsrf_token
session.headers['x-requested-with'] = 'XMLHttpRequest'

login = session.post(login_url, data={
    'login[userid]': 'HTWyou',
    'login[password]': 'kjh&*76dfgG',
    'login[remember_me]': False
})

#f = open('results.html', 'w', encoding = 'utf-8')
f = open('results.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
f.write(login.text)
f.close()

"""
# code to print the headers:
hdrs = login.request.headers
for k in sorted(hdrs.keys()):
    print(f'{k}: {hdrs[k]}')
"""

print(login.json())
```

Prints:

```py
{'success': True, 'url': '/', 'player_id': 851846598}
```

**The headers being passed up by the login XHR Request**

```
:authority: us.forgeofempires.com
:method: POST
:path: /glps/login_check
:scheme: https
accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
content-length: 74
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
cookie: device_view=full; metricsUvId=da9ca1f1-8e32-411f-ac7d-bf389df25469; portal_tid=1627319201921-36801; portal_ref_session=1; portal_ref_url=https://us0.forgeofempires.com/; portal_data=portal_tid=1627319201921-36801&portal_ref_session=1&portal_ref_url=https://us0.forgeofempires.com/; PHPSESSID=54955p3mbbstetnnquivk12rk2r0ihqmk41nagl620r5g9p5; XSRF-TOKEN=mQxleEoXU2Hyz6LP1ZlM7huHE-DLt5pg8qySl-M1vtI
dnt: 1
origin: https://us.forgeofempires.com
referer: https://us.forgeofempires.com/glps/iframe-login
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="92", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="92"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36
x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest
x-xsrf-token: mQxleEoXU2Hyz6LP1ZlM7huHE-DLt5pg8qySl-M1vtI
```

**The headers being passed up by `session.post`**

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 89
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie: PHPSESSID=86lis3h0s8291fgkto5r2lcnqr7a6c22nnotveeo2iuuusht; XSRF-TOKEN=Qxm6zfZrDqaI8ce7MDQ5rQqpHHOUozKaFu-NL2Av9KU; device_view=full
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0
x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest
x-xsrf-token: Qxm6zfZrDqaI8ce7MDQ5rQqpHHOUozKaFu-NL2Av9KU
```

Comment: The same... I get Response 200 message but when I open my results.html it still shows me a login page without being logged in... Also, when analysing network traffic when logging in manually, I don't see POST request at all...

Comment: I see the POST request. First of all, you have the wrong URL for the login POST and second you are missing a form variable and third the POST data must be sent up as JSON. I have also added a a couple of other headers that might be needed but probably not all. But not having the user id and password It cannot test further.  See the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! but this again didn't work... here are the credentials:HTWyou / kjh&*76dfgG. Also, do you have a good source start studying the issue? All Python login documentation I found is for simple HTM logins.